# Pandas find values that could be a date

Tags: python, pandas

I have large and messy dataframe and want to identify date-like values if there are any. These date-like values could have any kind of date format and data type.

Is there a generic (pandas in-built) way to achieve this?

My code:

```
>> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 267091 entries, 0 to 267090
Data columns (total 93 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------                          --------------   ----- 
 0   verbund                         267091 non-null  object
 1   verbund_id                      267091 non-null  object
 2   global_party                    267091 non-null  object
...
 91  kdberat_name_1                  241196 non-null  object
 92  is_divergent_f                  267091 non-null  int8  
dtypes: int8(1), object(92)
memory usage: 187.7+ MB

>> pd.to_datetime(csamapping_test.stack(), errors='coerce').unstack().info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 267091 entries, 0 to 267090
Data columns (total 93 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------                          --------------   -----         
 0   verbund                         0 non-null       datetime64[ns]
 1   verbund_id                      0 non-null       datetime64[ns]
 2   global_party                    0 non-null       datetime64[ns]
...
 91  kdberat_name_1                  0 non-null       datetime64[ns]
 92  is_divergent_f                  267091 non-null  datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](93)
memory usage: 191.5 MB
```

Comment: You can try to use `pd.to_datetime(array, errors='coerce')`, but without a specific example it's difficult to generalize

Comment: Do you have a specific format or set of formats that you are looking for? What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @rassar the format(s) are latent, if dates exist within the dataframe

Comment: Can you show us a bit of the data? a few rows/cols with the actual content. How many columns/row would you expect to contain dates?

Comment: @mozway due to privacy issues I can't. I already had a thorough look through the data and I still don't know what I am looking for. I manually checked for some common parts of date formats like "YYYY" or "YYYYMM". No matches. But this is actually what I wanted to ask with my question: Is there a smart way for finding date-like values if you have no clue what you are looking for? The answer to this might just be No.

Comment: Can't you generate a small example of dummy data using your human eye/brain to gives us something that looks like your data? Without that, the answer is likely **no** indeed.

Comment: Without knowing the formats (especially since there are multiple formats), pd.to_datetime probably won't help you and you will probably have to write something yourself.